# Is there a reason why this function only works once?

Tags: javascript, html, js-cookie

I am using JS-Cookie to make a simple clicker game. When I call the function, it works once, but then I have to refresh for the function to work again. I have tried adding a console.log after it to help debug it, and the log shows up, but the Cookies.set isn't working. I don't know what is happening and I'm not too familiar with this library so any help is appreciated.

**Javascript**

```js
(function refreshCookies(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        let flame = Cookies.get('flame');
        let gems = Cookies.get('gems');
        let cuid = Cookies.get('CUID');
        let username = Cookies.get('username');
        let value = Cookies.get('value');

        let value_amount = document.getElementById('value-amount');
        let flame_amount = document.getElementById('flame-amount');
        let gem_amount = document.getElementById('gem-amount');
        let board_placing = document.getElementById('board-placing');
        let welcome_username = document.getElementById('welcome-username');
        let username_header = document.getElementById('username-header');
        let title = document.getElementById('title');

        value_amount.innerHTML = "$" + value;
        flame_amount.innerHTML = "<i class=\"fas fa-fire-alt\"></i> " + flame;
        gem_amount.innerHTML = "<i class=\"fas fa-gem\"></i> " + gems;
        welcome_username.innerHTML = "Welcome, " + username + "!";
        username_header.innerHTML = username;
        title.innerHTML = "Shoe Clicker - $" + value;
        if (--i) {
            refreshCookies(i);
        }
    }, 0500);
})(Infinity);
// clicker

function addClick() {
    Cookies.set('value', parseInt(value) + 1);
    console.log('click added!');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section onclick="addClick();" class="clicker">
    <h2>Press anywhere to get money!<h2>
    <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
</section>
```

Comment: An errors in the console?

Comment: BTW you use `value` in `addClick` but you declared it in a different function

Comment: What do you mean by "only works once"? Do you mean the value only changes once (on the initial page load)?

Comment: There are no errors in the console and what I mean is, when I load the page, and I click, the function will work. But If I try to click again, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an increment to increase the value on each click . A simple demo is in below snippet .

```js
var money = 0
function addClick() {
  money++
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = money
}
```

```html
<section onclick="addClick();" class="clicker">
  <h2>Press on me to get money $ !</h2>
  <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
</section>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using cookies so that when you refresh, the amount of money you have is still there. So I can't use that.

Comment: Yes, you are right , I have given a demo only . Now as number is increasing , you can save this in your cookie

Comment: Oh, alright, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem , happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding something like this?

```
function addClick() {
    let value = Cookies.get('value');
    Cookies.set('value', parseInt(value) + 1);
    console.log('click added!');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).